# How do I uninstall Heroku?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, wget, heroku

I installed Heroku using

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Please tell me how to uninstall Heroku.

Comment: To anyone: 1 of the easiest method to -completely- -brick- your system is to run scripts from the web. NEVER EVER do things like this without analyzing the script and understanding what you are doing. I would rather you post the script here and have confirmed what it does that to just execute it and ask afterwards what to do ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I downloaded the script and it seems that all it does is insert its own repository URL into your sources list and then uses the apt-get package manager to install it.

To remove, it is really simple, just open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove heroku-toolbelt
```

Also, as a word of warning, try not to use scripts written by others to install applications. Some of them can contain extremely dangerous commands which could cause irreversible damage to your data. If you are unsure how to install an application, you can always search Ask Ubuntu for similar questions and answers.

Comment: Link to script: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I will take care to read script before running it.

Comment: @VinayakGarg good... I still added a warning though... if this was actual malware you could have in real trouble...

Comment: It cannot be stressed enough how dangerous it is to run random scripts from the internet without checking the contents of the script. All it would have took was one line of "rm -rf /" in between the sudo sh <<SCRIPT block to completely annihilate the whole OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the snap version of Heroku, you can do this:

```
snap remove heroku
```

Be sure to make a backup of your configuration if you will need it again.

Comment: thanks, I still have `/dev/loop1        119552  119552         0 100% /snap/core/14447` do I need to unmount or something too?